# What does this stack trace mean?

Tags: javascript, android, angularjs, google-chrome, memory-leaks

```
Devices tested on: Samsung S4, Ipad
Browsers : Chrome and Safari for mobile
Server : JBOSS 
Export type: war
```

Chrome and Safari (mobile) crash intermittently during regular use of my application. I sent in a crash report to google and received this back:
Thread 16 CRASHED [SIGABRT @ 0x000056e7] MAGIC SIGNATURE THREAD

```
0x40140134      [libc.so + 0x00022134 ] 
0x4013118b      [libc.so + 0x0001318b ] 
0x4013139f      [libc.so + 0x0001339f ] 
0x401300d5      [libc.so + 0x000120d5 ] 
0x4013f9ea      [libc.so + 0x000219ea ] 
0x64b07dd7      [dalvik-mark-stack (deleted) + 0x0222bdd7 ]     
0x40130bbb      [libc.so + 0x00012bbb ] 
0x4015e14d      [libc.so + 0x0004014d ] 
0x4012d2c7      [libc.so + 0x0000f2c7 ] 
0x4015e14d      [libc.so + 0x0004014d ] 
0x40161d2e      [libc.so + 0x00043d2e ] 
0x4012e1d3      [libc.so + 0x000101d3 ] 
0x4012df73      [libc.so + 0x0000ff73 ] 
0x4012bcff      [libc.so + 0x0000dcff ] 
0x78264ae7      [libchrome.2214.109.so -sqlite3.c:14539 ]       sqlite3MemRoundup
0x78264af7      [libchrome.2214.109.so -sqlite3.c:14468 ]       sqlite3MemMalloc
0x78264a8b      [libchrome.2214.109.so -sqlite3.c:17981 ]       mallocWithAlarm
0x78264a15      [libchrome.2214.109.so -sqlite3.c:18014 ]       sqlite3Malloc
0x7826513f      [libchrome.2214.109.so -sqlite3.c:18345 ]       sqlite3DbMallocRaw
0x78277773      [libchrome.2214.109.so -sqlite3.c:56058 ]       sqlite3VdbeMemGrow
0x782798f5      [libchrome.2214.109.so -sqlite3.c:64836 ]       sqlite3VdbeExec
0x78277c19      [libchrome.2214.109.so -sqlite3.c:60748 ]       sqlite3_step
0x7827e3eb      [libchrome.2214.109.so -statement.cc:61 ]       sql::Statement::Run
0x78196339      [libchrome.2214.109.so -sqlite_persistent_cookie_store.cc:1042 ]        content::SQLitePersistentCookieStore::Backend::Commit
0x781936c9      [libchrome.2214.109.so -callback.h:401 ]        base::SequencedWorkerPool::Inner::ThreadLoop
0x781930f5      [libchrome.2214.109.so -sequenced_worker_pool.cc:507 ]  base::SequencedWorkerPool::Worker::Run
0x78192f55      [libchrome.2214.109.so -simple_thread.cc:60 ]   base::SimpleThread::ThreadMain
0x7818674f      [libchrome.2214.109.so -platform_thread_posix.cc:80 ]   base::::ThreadFunc
0x4012b27a      [libc.so + 0x0000d27a ] 
0x4012b412      [libc.so + 0x0000d412 ] 
0x64b07dd7      [dalvik-mark-stack (deleted) + 0x0222bdd7 ]
```

I'm going to assume that there is **a memory leak** . How do I address this or track down the origins?

Please not that I do not make any explicit calls to sqlite using sqlite commands. However, I do make ample use of html5 localStorage and I have external JS libraries that make use of storage using cookies.

Comment: If the browsers themselves crash while running a web application then it's definitely a bug the vendors will be interested in knowing about. Especially if it affects multiple browsers. I would focus on reproducing the bug reliably and isolating it before filing reports; regardless of whether your application does something wrong or not, the crashes are not your fault.

Answer (score 1):

The stack trace shows you the path that the code follows during the execution of your application. It can help you to find were did the error took place.

Looks like the error is related with `sqlite3` in your stack trace. Each line inyour stak trace is a function in the code:

```
sqlite3MemRoundup
sqlite3MemMalloc
mallocWithAlarm
sqlite3Malloc
sqlite3DbMallocRaw
sqlite3VdbeMemGrow
sqlite3VdbeExec
sqlite3_step
```

You should investigate the parts of your application that use `sqlite`.

I don't think it is a JavaScript memory leak but you can use the Chrome memory Profiler to study the memory usage and find leaks https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/javascript-memory-profiling

Comment: Looks like is related with cookies, chrome is using sqlite internally when working with cookies. So  I would also research if you are trying to save cookies ``content::SQLitePersistentCookieStore::Backend::Commit``

Comment: I don't make any explicit calls to sqlite3 commands, I  have some external 3rd libraires that make use of cookies.  This is a good starting point for me , if it solves my problem  I will accept this answer.